# Error when trying to open/deactivate a process in Process Builder

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, process-builder, metadata-api, package

I have a rogue process that a previous employee made in Process Builder, and which tends to mess with the workflow we've since transitioned to, and since the process doesn't even do anything important, I'd like to deactivate it. But every time I try to open it in Process Builder in order to deactivate it I am met with the below error

[image]

I am Administrator and have all the necessary permissions, so I know it's not a permission issue.
I wrote the official Salesforce support, and after a long list of platitudes and non-answers they eventually informed me that it was due to this [open bug](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003UVoQAM) and that essentially I'd just have to suck it up.

However, that damn process is still causing me numerous problems and I'm wondering **if there's some other way to forcefully rid myself of it - such as through metadata deployment or workbench or some other approach that support did not mention?**

Otherwise, if I'm stuck with a destructive process that I can't remove, and which won't be fixed anytime soon, all I can think of is that I might have to completely migrate all my stuff to a different Salesforce org which would be a giant pain in the ass...

Comment: Have you tried editing the process itself to make it do nothing?

Comment: @PhilW Looks like the OP can't even open the Process to edit/clone/deactivate.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do this through a metadata deployment. If you have a test environment, you can try this out to see if it works. In API version 44.0 and later, you can do this all through the Flow metadata type (no need for FlowDefinition).

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm

You'll want to pull the flow in the package.xml with workbench (or VS/DX if you use it).

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Flow</name>
    </types>
    <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

Go into the flow in question's XML and update the Status value from "Active" to "Draft"

[image]

Repackage and deploy through workbench (or simply deploy through VS Code)